# Click event does not work with custom cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, pointer-events, custom-cursor

I am trying to create a custom cursor on a website (a blurry yellow spot). I created a div in HTML for the custom cursor and styled it in CSS. I gave the 'cursor: none' property to the body tag to hide the default cursor. I also put 'pointer-events: none' on the custom cursor div. Still, click events are not (or hardly) working on buttons (for example I cannot close a pop-up window with the close button). When I remove 'cursor: none', everything works fine, but the default cursor returns beside the yellow spot. Could you please help me in solving this? How could I remove the default cursor without affecting click events? Thank you in advance.

```js
// move yellow spot as cursor
const moveCursor = (e) => {
    const mouseY = e.clientY;
    const mouseX = e.clientX;
    const yellowSpot = document.querySelector(".yellow-spot");
    yellowSpot.style.transform = `translate3d(${mouseX}px, ${mouseY}px, 0)`;
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Button clicked");
});
```

```css
*,
body {
    cursor: none !important;
}

.yellow-spot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1.625rem;
    height: 1.625rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffeb77;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #ffeb77;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-spot"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: I copied your code blocks into a stack snippet and added a button. I can click the button. It's tricky because the cursor is at the top left of the spot but people would expect it to be in the center. Does the stack snippet reflect what you're actually doing? You should be able to click (if you pay attention to where the cursor actually is; easier if, for debugging, you remove the `cursor: none`).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the actual cursor is at the top-left of the yellow spot, not in the middle, so it's easy to miss things when trying to click on them. You can see that if you remove the `cursor: none` rule:

```js
// move yellow spot as cursor
const moveCursor = (e) => {
    const mouseY = e.clientY;
    const mouseX = e.clientX;
    const yellowSpot = document.querySelector(".yellow-spot");
    yellowSpot.style.transform = `translate3d(${mouseX}px, ${mouseY}px, 0)`;
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Button clicked");
});
```

```css
*,
body {
    /* cursor: none !important; */
}

.yellow-spot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1.625rem;
    height: 1.625rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffeb77;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #ffeb77;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-spot"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
```

To fix it, center the yellow spot over the cursor rather than moving it to the top-left (I also changed *how* the yellow spot is moved, but that's not the important thing):

```js
const yellowSpot = document.querySelector('.yellow-spot');
// move the yellow spot to the mouse position
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    // Make sure the *center* of the yellow spot is where the
    // cursor is, not the top left
    const {clientWidth, clientHeight} = yellowSpot;
    yellowSpot.style.left = ((e.pageX - (clientWidth / 2)) + 'px');
    yellowSpot.style.top = (e.pageY - (clientHeight / 2)) + 'px';
});
```

```css
*,
body {
    cursor: none !important;
}

.yellow-spot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1.625rem;
    height: 1.625rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffeb77;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #ffeb77;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-spot"></div>
<button onclick="alert('test')">Click me</button>
```

Here's a version with the cursor showing so you can see how it's centered in the yellow spot now:

```js
const yellowSpot = document.querySelector('.yellow-spot');
// move the yellow spot to the mouse position
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    // Make sure the *center* of the yellow spot is where the
    // cursor is, not the top left
    const {clientWidth, clientHeight} = yellowSpot;
    yellowSpot.style.left = ((e.pageX - (clientWidth / 2)) + 'px');
    yellowSpot.style.top = (e.pageY - (clientHeight / 2)) + 'px';
});
```

```css
*,
body {
    /*cursor: none !important;*/
}

.yellow-spot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 1.625rem;
    height: 1.625rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffeb77;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px #ffeb77;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-spot"></div>
<button onclick="alert('test')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: The issue with the click because he clicks with `yellow-spot` not with the actual `cursor` so I just centered the actual `cursor` in `yellow-spot` and the click event works fine

Comment: In both two JS codes, the `yellow-spot` following the cursor correctly. But to understand what I'm saying, try to `cursor: none !important;` and track `cursor ` location in both codes. In the first case, you can see the  `yellow-spot` appear on the `button` but the `cursor` not so, when we center the  `cursor` in the `yellow-spot` we can make sure the `cursor` is on the `button`

Comment: It's not about how to move the `yellow-spot`

Comment: I did that and put the OP's code back, and it still worked. Did you change anything other than the code in `moveCursor`? (Again, explanation and saying what you did would **really** help.) But removing the `cursor: none` shows that the yellow spot really needs to be positioned differently, people are going to expect the click in the middle of that spot, not the top left.

Comment: I took the liberty of substantially updating the answer to add an explanation and to center the yellow spot over the cursor correctly rather than only partially. Please use the rollback feature if you don't want the edit, but I think it more clearly explains what you've tried to explain in the comments.